# How to get egrep to match ^ for every line (as it should be)

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file containing these lines:

```
SOME COMMAND 34 XXXXX ;
; a comment which may contain a : 
      sometext001 : X00 : 1 ;
                  : X01 : 1 ;
                  : X11 : 1 ;
```

And want to retrieve `sometext001` with grep/egrep.

Using the regex `^\s*[^:\s;]+\s*:`

(in words: starting at the beginning of the line with some or none whitespace, followed by at least one character not a whitespace, colon or semicolon followed again by some or none whitespaces followed by a colon)

I'm able to match the text (including the following :) using an online regex tester http://regexr.com?35eam if I enable multiline support.

I was under the impression that grep/egrep works line by line anyway, so why does the regex not work when used with egrep on a file containing this example?

Is there another way to achive the desired result with egrep or, if that's not possible, with another one-liner callable from a shell script?

**Update:** although the proposed change of the regex to `^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:];]+[[:space:]]*:` matches the lines specified, it it still matches twice in that line, once for `sometext001 :` and once for `X00 :` as evident when using the -o option to egrep.
How to solve this?

**Update:** The test file contained exactly the text given above. The command line was `egrep -o '^([[:space:]]*[^:[:space:];]+[[:space:]]*:)' test.txt` (also tried without the () pair). Output is

```
      sometext001 :
X00 :
```

Comment: you are correct, grep works line by line. You can't use grep on multiline (as you are trying to do here)

Comment: @KingJohnno Can you explain to my what is multi-line in my regex? I'm only trying to match characters in one line of text. No fancy look-ahead or look-behind, no explicit newlines etc.

Comment: I miss understood your code that you posted - I believed the ':' to indicate the new line. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: `egrep -o '^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:];]+[[:space:]]*:'` matches only once for me with your sample input.  Can you cut-n-paste your command line, its actual output, and a representative test file?

Comment: I've updated the question with the exact command line and the output.

Answer (score 2):

`egrep` uses [POSIX EREs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) by default, and those don't recognize `\s` and other Perl-style shorthands. Try

```
^[[:space:]]*[^:[:space:];]+[[:space:]]*:
```

Comment: "don't recognize" doesn't seem to be entirely true. I can search for `\s` alone and will get valid results (at least nothing that matches only \s literally)

Comment: Although it solves my problem, I've removed the 'correct answer' flag again. I still believe it had something to do with the way egrep handles newlines and the question about that was not answered.

Answer (score 1):

You should better use `-P` (perl like regex switch) with the regex that you have:

```
grep -P '^\s*[^:\s;]+\s*:'
```

Comment: `-P` doesn't seem to be a valid option in my version of grep (GNU grep 2.5.1)

Answer (score 0):

with gnu grep:

```
grep -Po '^\s*\K[^\s:;]*(?= :)'
```

with yourexample:

```
kent$  echo "SOME COMMAND 34 XXXXX ;
; a comment which may contain a : 
      sometext001 : X00 : 1 ;
                  : X00 : 1 ;
                  : X11 : 1 ;"|grep -Po '^\s*\K[^\s:;]*(?= :)'
sometext001
```

Comment: -P doesn't seem to be a valid option in my version of grep (GNU grep 2.5.1)